# Configuration default Values not showing in magento 2

Tags: configuration, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta, system-config

I have set default file name in textbox but it's not working. Can you please guide me where I went wrong?

my Code is:

**app/code/learning/Custom/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="0">
            <label>Custom Extension</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Customer</label>
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Learning_Custom::config_custom</resource>
            <group id="magento_customer_logs" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Magento Customer Logs</label>
                <field id="magento_request" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Magento Customer Request</label>
                </field>
                <field id="magento_response" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Magento Customer Response</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/learning/Custom/etc/acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Learning_Custom::config_custom" title="Custom Section" sortOrder="80" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**app/code/learning/Custom/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <custom_customer>
            <magento_customer_logs>
                <magento_request>magento_request</magento_request>
                <magento_response>magento_response</magento_response>
            </magento_customer_logs>
        </custom_customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

Could you please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: you have to remaining declare your modulename(Custom) in code.plz keep all the file inside Custom Folder. like app/code/learning/Custom/

Comment: @RBJesadiya, Sorry, I forgot to Include Module name now I have updated my code plz.. look on this.

Comment: What is magento version you using ?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.0.0-beta.

Comment: I think you should write uppercase Learning and try refactor again

Comment: @PsW, I have already fallowed Camel Case right? Then Where should I write? have you find any where in my code please let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="0">
            <label>Custom Extension
        </tab>
        <section id="custom_customer" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Customer</label>
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Learning_Custom::config_custom</resource>
            <group id="magento_customer_logs" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Magento Customer Logs</label>
                <field id="magento_request" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Magento Customer Request</label>
                </field>
                <field id="magento_response" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Magento Customer Response</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

acl.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Learning_Custom::config_custom" title="Custom Section" sortOrder="80" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

config.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <custom_customer>
            <magento_customer_logs>
                <magento_request>magento_request</magento_request>
                <magento_response>magento_response</magento_response>
            </magento_customer_logs>
        </custom_customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

Try it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to Include Module name now I have updated my code plz.. look on this.

Comment: Yes it's working in newly released MCE 1.0.0 and MEE 1.0.0